# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive for style-src

Tags: http-headers, response-headers, content-security-policy

I've removed all the inline CSS from my application which were present before.

But still I'm getting error as "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon [https://atlas.microsoft.com/"](https://atlas.microsoft.com/%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I can't use unsafe-inline due to security point of view in production environment.

Please suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'unsafe-inline' is not a big a big problem if you're able to restrict the rest of your CSP: https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/

Check the links in your console errors to check where the errors are reported and find the offenders. Style attributes and scripts outputting styles are also counted as inline styles.